# Firefox keep the old version after update

Tags: firefox, linux-mint

Recently I wanted to update my firefox. 
First I uninstall it:

```
sudo apt-get remove firefox
```

Add the mozilla repository to sources.list
https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ppa

Then install the firefox:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

After installation, in command line, I type this:

```
firefox --version
```

Result: Mozilla Firefox 14.0.1
However, when run firefox, 
In Help > About Firefox, it is still showing version as 9.0.1
Am I missing anything ? I am using linux mint. 
Thanks,

Comment: Could it be you additionally installed FF9 manually, and it's in the PATH *before* this one? Check e.g. `/usr/local/bin` (comes before `/usr/bin` where the apt-installed one resides).

Comment: Hi. It shouldn't be manually installed. I remember it is bundled with the linux mint distributiobn

Comment: Sure it is. But that doesn't mean you could not have it installed manually (and sometimes there are good reasons to do so) -- so it was just a thought. Did you check the paths? Also a `which firefox` from the terminal might help to show which one is used.

Answer (score 0):

As @Izzy said, try

```
which -a firefox
```

You will probably get two entries. You can check your $PATH by:

```
echo $PATH
```

You can modify it (among other ways) by editing/adding this line to your ~/.bashrc file:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:$PATH
```

Make sure to modify the line as needed for your directory structure. Again as Izzy said, make sure that the directory where the newer firefox binary is installed is *before* the one where the older version is.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I have installed using deb package. So the bin is updated by the new one. Which -a firefox show one entry: /usr/bin/firefox only. Now I see the version reflected under Help is 14. I guess I need to restart my computer?

Comment: @khue-vu Probably just had to restart firefox :)So everything ok now?